# Event Listener Only Adds Class For A Second - I Want It Permanent

Tags: javascript, html, css

Working on a side nav that appears when I click on the burger menu. I am relatively new to this. I'm using event listeners to add and remove a class. But what's happening is the click is registered, the transition starts and then is cut off and doesn't continue, it goes back to original state.

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".burgerMenu");
const sMenu = document.querySelector("#sideMenu");
const bI1 = document.querySelector(".burgerIcon1");
const bI2 = document.querySelector(".burgerIcon2");
const bI3 = document.querySelector(".burgerIcon3");

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!sMenu.classList.contains('menuAway')) {
    sMenu.classList.add('menuAway');
  } else {
    sMenu.classList.remove('menuAway');
  }

  if (!bI1.classList.contains('oneOnClick')) {
    bI1.classList.add('oneOnClick');
  } else {
    bI1.classList.remove('oneOnClick');
  }

  if (!bI2.classList.contains('twoOnClick')) {
    bI2.classList.add('twoOnClick');
  } else {
    bI2.classList.remove('twoOnClick');
  }

  if (!bI3.classList.contains('threeOnClick')) {
    bI3.classList.add('threeOnClick');
  } else {
    bI3.classList.remove('threeOnClick');
  }
})
```

```css
.menu {
  background: var(--gradient);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 38%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 5%;
  opacity: 0.92;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.menuAway {
  right: -75vw;
}

.menu li {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 4rem;
}

.menu li:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.burgerMenu {
  z-index: 4;
}

.burgerIcon {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background-color: #282828;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.oneOnClick {
  transform: translate(0px, 8px) rotate(45deg);
}

.twoOnClick {
  width: 0px;
}

.threeOnClick {
  transform: translate(0px, -8px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="navParent">
  <div class="navBar">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="Assets/logo.svg" alt="Inform Logo" class="smallLogo">
    </a>
    <a href="" class="burgerMenu">
      <div class="burgerIcon burgerIcon1"></div>
      <div class="burgerIcon burgerIcon2"></div>
      <div class="burgerIcon burgerIcon3"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <section class="menu menuAway" id="sideMenu">
    <ul>
      <a href="about.html">
        <li>About Us</li>
      </a>
      <a href="projects.html">
        <li>Projects</li>
      </a>
      <a href="articles.html">
        <li>Articles</li>
      </a>
      <a href="contact.html">
        <li>Contact Us</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of the `<a href="">` so when you click the link you actually navigate, causing the page to reload. I suggest replacing the link with a button, or for a quick fix, do `<a href="javascript:void(0)">`

Also, you can make your code a lot easier to read by using `classList.toggle` instead of the `if/else` blocks

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle
E.g. replace

```
if (!sMenu.classList.contains('menuAway')) {
    sMenu.classList.add('menuAway');
  } else {
    sMenu.classList.remove('menuAway');
  }
```

With

```
sMenu.classList.toggle('menuAway')
```